# What actually happens if you pour a glaze over a loaf cake before it has cooled?

Tags: baking, cake, food-science, texture, icing

Taking a regular loaf cake, say a pound cake, and a glaze of about 3/4 cup confectioners sugar to 2 Tablespoons liquid:

What actually happens if you pour a glaze/coating over a still hot or warm cake?

Does it soak it through, set up as it should, or drip a lot? How does it affect the consistency of the cake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The icing will seem like it's melting and soak though the pound cake. The effect will be similar to soaking the cake with simple syrup. A pound cake is fairly 'solid' so the consistency shouldn't be affected very much, unless you use enormous amounts of icing.